# highfreqency package error Error in if (a < b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to use the rRTSCov function and I get an error

```
   library(highfrequency)
head(all)
dim(all)

class(all$Price)
all$Price <- as.numeric(all$Price)
class(all$Price)
sum(is.na(as.numeric(all$Price))) ## of NAs

xt<- as.xts(all, order.by= as.POSIXct(all$Time) )
head(xt)
l<- list(xt)
class(l)
head(l[[1]])
dim(l[[1]])
rRTSCov(l, cor=FALSE, startIV=NULL, noisevar = NULL, 
        K = 300 , J = 1, K_cov = NULL , J_cov = NULL,
        K_var = NULL , J_var = NULL, eta = 9, makePsd = FALSE)
```

OUTPUT:

```
> library(highfrequency)
> head(all)
                           Time  Price
1 2015/06/29 09:30:00.127000000 163.98
2 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.92
3 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
4 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
5 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
6 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.99
> dim(all)
[1] 29148     2
> class(all$Price)
[1] "numeric"
> all$Price <- as.numeric(all$Price)
> sum(is.na(as.numeric(all$Price))) ## of NAs
[1] 0
> xt<- as.xts(all, order.by= as.POSIXct(all$Time) )
> head(xt)
                    Time                            Price     
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.127000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9200"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9900"
> l<- list(xt)
> class(l)
[1] "list"
> head(l[[1]])
                    Time                            Price     
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.127000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9200"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000" "163.9900"
> dim(l[[1]])
[1] 29148     2
> rRTSCov(l, cor=FALSE, startIV=NULL, noisevar = NULL, 
+         K = 300 , J = 1, K_cov = NULL , J_cov = NULL,
+         K_var = NULL , J_var = NULL, eta = 9, makePsd = FALSE)
Error in if (a < b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as.double.xts(pdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as.double.xts(pdata) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

any idea why it is saying Error in if (a < b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Thank you.

Comment: Why is your `price` column is a character vector rather than numeric? Try changing it with `all$Price <- as.numeric(all$Price)`. If that gives you a "NAs introduced" warning, you need to look at those rows in your original `all` data with `all[is.na(as.numeric(all$Price))]`, because they contain something that can't be converted into numbers. For example, they may contain commas

Comment: there looks to be 0 NAs and the vector is numeric already hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

`rRTSCov` asks for a list of `xts` objects, but you are passing it a list with a `ts` object:

```
xt<-as.ts(all$Price)
```

This will work if you convert the `ts` object into an `xts` object. Change that line to:

```
xt<-as.xts(as.ts(all$Price))
```

The reason you were getting an error is that `nrow` doesn't work on a ts object, but does on xts. For example:

```
nrow(as.ts(1:5))
# NULL
nrow(as.xts(as.ts(1:5)))
# 5
```

Comment: i changed my code to have the date included as well and now I get the error above